# Erase elements from one vector and add them to another vector using do-while

Tags: c++, vector, do-while

I am trying to build a function which erases elements from a vector's top and adds them to another vector's bottom using a do-while loop (`while bb.begin() != bb.end()`).

I didn't expect it to work in the situation when there is only one element left in the vector since it is the last element. But my code works, even for the last element, while `(bb = numberSearch.end()`

How did this happen?

```
vector<int> numberSearch;
vector<int> numberpool;

//set init values
for (int k =0; k<6; k++)
{
    numberSearch.push_back(k);
    numberpool.push_back(k * 10);
}

//add and remove
vector<int>::iterator bb = numberSearch.begin();
do
{
    cout << "current numberSearch= " << *bb << endl;
    numberpool.push_back(*bb);
    numberSearch.erase(bb);
} while (bb != numberSearch.end());

//output
vector<int>::iterator cc = numberpool.begin();
for(; cc !=numberpool.end(); cc++)
{
    cout<< "numberpool=" <<*cc <<endl;
}

//ouput
for(; bb !=numberSearch.end(); bb++)
{
    cout<< "numberpool=" <<*bb <<endl;
}
```

the output is like:

```
current numberSearch= 0  
current numberSearch= 1  
current numberSearch= 2  
current numberSearch= 3  
current numberSearch= 4  
current numberSearch= 5  
numberpool=0  
numberpool=10  
numberpool=20  
numberpool=30  
numberpool=40  
numberpool=50  
numberpool=0  
numberpool=1  
numberpool=2  
numberpool=3  
numberpool=4  
numberpool=5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is actually not valid, because you are using an iterator after removing the element which it refers to. Hence, the code exhibits undefined behaviour. The way to fix this, would be to change the line:

```
numberSearch.erase(bb);
```

into

```
bb = numberSearch.erase(bb);
```

As for why this (with fix) works even when only one element is in the list:

`end()` returns an iterator to "one past the end" of the vector. That is, it is an iterator to just after the last element of the vector. As such, it will be inequal to the first element, even in a vector containing only one element.

Answer (score 0):

The `end()` iterator does not point to the last element. It is an iterator past that element. Hence all your elements get deleted.

`rbegin()` is an iterator that points to the last element.

Also, as mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

> Iterators, pointers and references pointing to position (or first) and
>   beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to
>   elements before position (or first) are guaranteed to keep referring
>   to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Hence as suggested, you should make bb equal to the return value of erase function.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use built in functions instead of `do-while`:

```
numberpool.insert(numberpool.end(), numberSearch.begin(), numberSearch.end());
numberSearch.erase(numberSearch.begin(), numberSearch.end());
```

Comment: While this is a good tip, it doesn't address the question asked and as such would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: this built-in function surely makes more sense